# Add dependence project to XCode

Tags: xcode

I deleted a building dependency by accident, and want to add it back like this:

[image]

and I have already checkout it from another git branch as a subfolder of the main project folder, in the subfolder, there is a `.xcodeproj` there

I google around and some one says that I should drag/drop the `.xcodeproj` or the entire subfolder to the project explorer, but either works
Here is the subfolder in the main project folder

[image]

So how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured this out:

This thing is called `workplace` designed to manage multi-project in one Xcode instance

To add a project to the workplace, you should

1. Open the `projectName.workplace` instead of `projectName.xcodeproj`
2. File -> add Files to "youWorkPlaceName" -> select the `projectToadd.xcodeproj` and choose what the sh*t options Xcodes give's (if you can understand, [this tutorial video will help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNU6L2pnq0k)) and Click add

Then you are ok.